# I don't understand why my pointer doesn't behave like one in my function

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm learning linear data structures in C for my uni course, and I'm stuck on a simple task.
I keep getting segmentation fault (pretty general, sorry), but I really don't understand where I'm wrong.
Here's my function.

```
void findPosLDS(TypeLDS input, InfoTypeLDS req, TypeLDS *out){
    if (input -> info == req){
        *out = input;
        printf("add: %p val: %d add out:%p\n", &input, input -> info,
            out); 
        return;
    }
    else if (input -> next == NULL){
        *out = NULL;
        return;
    }
    findPosLDS(input -> next, req, out);
}
```

This function should iterate recursively over my lds ('input') looking for an integer ('req'), and copying the address of the node which contains the value I'm looking for in 'out'.

Here's the struct for my lds:

```
typedef int InfoTypeLDS;
struct elemLDS{
    InfoTypeLDS info;
    struct elemLDS* next;
};
typedef struct elemLDS NodeTypeLDS;
typedef NodeTypeLDS* TypeLDS;
```

Also, 'out' is declared as `TypeLDS *out` in main and initialized to NULL.

I tried not to deference 'out', by using `out = &input` which works correctly and it contains the right address, but only inside the function itself.
I believe the issue is that somehow by not deferencing it I'm not actually accessing the pointer itself, rather a copy, hence why it still points to NULL in main.

As asked, here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lds_struct.h"

TypeLDS createNode();
void addHeadNotRand(TypeLDS* lds, InfoTypeLDS elem);
void findPosLDS(TypeLDS input, InfoTypeLDS req, TypeLDS *out);
void printf_LDS(TypeLDS in);

    int main(){
        TypeLDS head = createNode();
        addHeadNotRand(&head, 3);
        addHeadNotRand(&head, 1);
        addHeadNotRand(&head, 65);
        addHeadNotRand(&head, 34);
        addHeadNotRand(&head, 2);
        TypeLDS *out = NULL;
        printf_LDS(head);
        findPosLDS(head, 65, out);
        printf("add: %p\n", out);
        return 0;
    }
    
    TypeLDS createNode(){
        TypeLDS out = (TypeLDS) malloc (sizeof(NodeTypeLDS));
        out -> next = NULL;
        return out;
    }
    
    void addHeadNotRand(TypeLDS* lds, InfoTypeLDS elem){
        TypeLDS temp = *lds;
        *lds = (TypeLDS) malloc (sizeof(NodeTypeLDS));
        (*lds) -> info = elem;
        (*lds) -> next = temp;
    }
    
    void findPosLDS(TypeLDS input, InfoTypeLDS req, TypeLDS *out){
        if (input -> info == req){
            *out = input;
            printf("add: %p val: %d add out:%p\n", &input, input -> info,
                out); 
            return;
        }
        else if (input -> next == NULL){
            *out = NULL;
            return;
        }
        findPosLDS(input -> next, req, out);
    }
    
    void printf_LDS(TypeLDS in){
        if (in -> next == NULL){
            printf("\n");
            return;
        }
        else{
            printf("%2d ", in -> info);
        }
        printf_LDS(in -> next);
    }
```

Comment: the code looks correct, except that it will crash due to stack overflow if your linked list is very long.

Comment: true, no I fully realize how inefficient recursion is in this case, but I wanted to use it to gain confidence with recursion. The linked list itself is of 5 nodes tho.

Comment: then the next possible culprit would be in code that you have not shown: the code which initializes the linked list.  `next` might be pointing to nonsense, or it may be forming a circular list, in which case what you ***think*** of as 5 nodes is actually an infinite number of nodes.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Just added the full script. @MikeNakis that makes sense, but no I'm positive the list is linear.

Comment: you are initializing `out` to `NULL` and then you are passing it to `findPosLDS()` which proceeds to store something in the address pointed by `out`.

Comment: Apparently this is some exercise where some code is given (and should not be changed), and other code must be implemented. Which part is the code that *you* have written? Are the functions parameter types and return types given? Cannot be altered? Is `main` code given?

Comment: Nope, nothing is given really, I just wanted to try something while studying. I can alter anything.

Comment: @MikeNakis thank you so much, yes that was the problem indeed. I was misled by the waring telling me I had to initialize it to NULL (I thought it was good practice to initialize new pointers to NULL?)

Comment: No, it is not good practice to initialize pointers to NULL.  You should initialize a pointer with a meaningful value.  If in a particular situation NULL happens to be meaningful, then go ahead and initialize with NULL. But if NULL is not meaningful, then do not use it just to initialize a pointer with it. Leave the pointer uninitialized, so that the compiler will issue a warning if you try to read the value of the pointer before writing to it.  (And it goes without saying: enable absolutely all warnings your compiler can give.)